# How to identify precision, recall, IoU, and mAP in these results for my trained Tensorflow model?

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection, model-evaluations, metric

I have trained a Single Shot Detector model (using Tensorflow), and have run the evaluation metrics. However, I am not entirely sure what to make of them. Doing a computer vision literature search, common evaluation metrics reported on are precision, recall, intersect-over-union (IoU), and mean average precision (mAP). Being new to object detection, I am trying to obtain these results, but am struggling to understand which metric to choose for precision, recall, mAP, etc. Algorithms such as YOLOv5 will automatically compute average precision/recall, mAP @ 0.5, etc., but those results are a little different than what Tensorflow provides. (Note: I trained the model with a Ubuntu 18.04 machine in the method [described in this tutorial](https://gilberttanner.com/blog/tensorflow-object-detection-with-tensorflow-2-creating-a-custom-model)).

Here are the results:

```
INFO:tensorflow:DONE (t=0.02s)
I1027 11:06:36.038156 139881781995328 coco_tools.py:138] DONE (t=0.02s)
creating index...
index created!
Running per image evaluation...
Evaluate annotation type *bbox*
DONE (t=5.55s).
Accumulating evaluation results...
DONE (t=0.41s).
 Average Precision  (AP) @[ IoU=0.50:0.95 | area=   all | maxDets=100 ] = 0.375
 Average Precision  (AP) @[ IoU=0.50      | area=   all | maxDets=100 ] = 0.684
 Average Precision  (AP) @[ IoU=0.75      | area=   all | maxDets=100 ] = 0.376
 Average Precision  (AP) @[ IoU=0.50:0.95 | area= small | maxDets=100 ] = 0.159
 Average Precision  (AP) @[ IoU=0.50:0.95 | area=medium | maxDets=100 ] = 0.363
 Average Precision  (AP) @[ IoU=0.50:0.95 | area= large | maxDets=100 ] = 0.382
 Average Recall     (AR) @[ IoU=0.50:0.95 | area=   all | maxDets=  1 ] = 0.148
 Average Recall     (AR) @[ IoU=0.50:0.95 | area=   all | maxDets= 10 ] = 0.454
 Average Recall     (AR) @[ IoU=0.50:0.95 | area=   all | maxDets=100 ] = 0.577
 Average Recall     (AR) @[ IoU=0.50:0.95 | area= small | maxDets=100 ] = 0.250
 Average Recall     (AR) @[ IoU=0.50:0.95 | area=medium | maxDets=100 ] = 0.541
 Average Recall     (AR) @[ IoU=0.50:0.95 | area= large | maxDets=100 ] = 0.585
INFO:tensorflow:Eval metrics at step 100000
I1027 11:06:42.064121 139881781995328 model_lib_v2.py:1007] Eval metrics at step 100000
INFO:tensorflow:        + DetectionBoxes_Precision/mAP: 0.375002
I1027 11:06:42.090729 139881781995328 model_lib_v2.py:1010]     + DetectionBoxes_Precision/mAP: 0.375002
INFO:tensorflow:        + DetectionBoxes_Precision/mAP@.50IOU: 0.684183
I1027 11:06:42.092986 139881781995328 model_lib_v2.py:1010]     + DetectionBoxes_Precision/mAP@.50IOU: 0.684183
INFO:tensorflow:        + DetectionBoxes_Precision/mAP@.75IOU: 0.376293
I1027 11:06:42.094577 139881781995328 model_lib_v2.py:1010]     + DetectionBoxes_Precision/mAP@.75IOU: 0.376293
INFO:tensorflow:        + DetectionBoxes_Precision/mAP (small): 0.159241
I1027 11:06:42.096016 139881781995328 model_lib_v2.py:1010]     + DetectionBoxes_Precision/mAP (small): 0.159241
INFO:tensorflow:        + DetectionBoxes_Precision/mAP (medium): 0.362854
I1027 11:06:42.097296 139881781995328 model_lib_v2.py:1010]     + DetectionBoxes_Precision/mAP (medium): 0.362854
INFO:tensorflow:        + DetectionBoxes_Precision/mAP (large): 0.381929
I1027 11:06:42.098785 139881781995328 model_lib_v2.py:1010]     + DetectionBoxes_Precision/mAP (large): 0.381929
INFO:tensorflow:        + DetectionBoxes_Recall/AR@1: 0.147922
I1027 11:06:42.100110 139881781995328 model_lib_v2.py:1010]     + DetectionBoxes_Recall/AR@1: 0.147922
INFO:tensorflow:        + DetectionBoxes_Recall/AR@10: 0.454406
I1027 11:06:42.101474 139881781995328 model_lib_v2.py:1010]     + DetectionBoxes_Recall/AR@10: 0.454406
INFO:tensorflow:        + DetectionBoxes_Recall/AR@100: 0.576815
I1027 11:06:42.102799 139881781995328 model_lib_v2.py:1010]     + DetectionBoxes_Recall/AR@100: 0.576815
INFO:tensorflow:        + DetectionBoxes_Recall/AR@100 (small): 0.250000
I1027 11:06:42.104048 139881781995328 model_lib_v2.py:1010]     + DetectionBoxes_Recall/AR@100 (small): 0.250000
INFO:tensorflow:        + DetectionBoxes_Recall/AR@100 (medium): 0.541326
I1027 11:06:42.105308 139881781995328 model_lib_v2.py:1010]     + DetectionBoxes_Recall/AR@100 (medium): 0.541326
INFO:tensorflow:        + DetectionBoxes_Recall/AR@100 (large): 0.584876
I1027 11:06:42.106697 139881781995328 model_lib_v2.py:1010]     + DetectionBoxes_Recall/AR@100 (large): 0.584876
INFO:tensorflow:        + Loss/localization_loss: 0.212005
I1027 11:06:42.107778 139881781995328 model_lib_v2.py:1010]     + Loss/localization_loss: 0.212005
INFO:tensorflow:        + Loss/classification_loss: 0.288771
I1027 11:06:42.108886 139881781995328 model_lib_v2.py:1010]     + Loss/classification_loss: 0.288771
INFO:tensorflow:        + Loss/regularization_loss: 0.279903
I1027 11:06:42.110019 139881781995328 model_lib_v2.py:1010]     + Loss/regularization_loss: 0.279903
INFO:tensorflow:        + Loss/total_loss: 0.780679
I1027 11:06:42.111117 139881781995328 model_lib_v2.py:1010]     + Loss/total_loss: 0.780679
```

Again, I'm looking for precision, recall, IoU, and mAP and am wanting to report on them in a similar manner that YOLO povides. Do I need to average all of the precision and recall scores to get those scores, or do I just need to look at one specific output?